# how to charge amount at beginning of billing cycle in paypal

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Let say I have an Plan which has setup fee 0 and billing amount $10 per day.

I have created a suscription for that plan, i have configured a webhook for payment.sale.created , but when a user subscribe to that plan he is not paying any amount on the day of subsription. Ex. if he subscriber on june 1,2020 he is not charging when he subscribes. Amount is deducted from his account on next day i.e, June 2,2020.

How can I charge him on the day of subscription i.e, immediately when he subscribes to a plan he must be charged and setup fee should be 0.

according to documentation of paypal subscription :
For example, if a subscription is $10 USD a week and the subscriber signs up on Tuesday, December 23, the subscriber is billed as follows:

```
Tuesday, December 23 = $10.00 USD
Tuesday, December 30 = $10.00 USD
Tuesday, January 6 = $10.00 USD
```

But this is not happening in sandbox testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I charge him on the day of subscription i.e, immediately when he subscribes to a plan he must be charged and setup fee should be 0.

What you are describing is exactly what the setup_fee is for. If you want to charge anything on the day of creation, use setup_fee.

Otherwise, you have to wait for the billing engine to process the next cycle, which **will not happen on that same day** , that is not how subscription billing works.

It is, however, how setup_fee works -- so setup_fee is there if you need this feature of billing on the same day.

You can combine setup_fee with a one week free trial, for example, if you need to ensure an immediate billing at the moment of checkout.

Comment: Hi, Preston we also implemented same approach, PayPal is charging our customer twice for each fee.
we want to make this subscription postpaid for each cycle.